# Tensorflow regression neural network outputting the same number for everything

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, regression

I have created a very simple regression model that trains of B&W images and corresponding labels between 0.5-10. When training to predict the label, it always converges to a model that outputs the same number for everything, that number looking most likely to be the average of all the labels. Is there something about my model that is creating this? My code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = np.load("dataset.npy", allow_pickle=True)

train_labels = list(map(float, train_labels))
test_labels = list(map(float, test_labels))
train_labels = [int(i) for i in train_labels]
test_labels = [int(i) for i in test_labels]

print(train_labels)

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(128, 128)),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
  ])

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=1000)

predictions = model.predict(test_images)

for i in range(103):
    print("%s: %s" % (test_labels[i], predictions[i]))
```

Comment: how many data samples you have? 
Since you use mean absolute error, the neural network, if it predicts the mean value of all the output values, then the loss automatically reduces to 50%. 
Did you normalize your data and output ?

Comment: it basically suggest that your model cannot learn anything. There could be many possible reasons. But you may first try using `Conv2d` layers instead of `Flatten` & `Dense` layers.

Comment: I had 410 datapoints, split into 328 for training and 82 for testing. By normalizing, do you mean mapping between 0 and 1? If so, no I did not. Should I?

Comment: @meowongac I used conv2d and pooling layers, and it seems to learn pretty consistently, but still only learns to output the same number.

Comment: in your example, try to use first a different activation function - 'relu' tend to be dead on the spot and the output of `Dense(64)` after 1000 epochs could be as well be zero. What you will get is then a bias value of `Dense(1)`. Also, plot and show distribution of your labels please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One crucial step when working with images is normalizing the image values. It helps with smooth optimization and gradient updates and also helps your model converge better and faster. There are various ways to do that but one of the simple normalization schemes is to divide the values of image pixels by 255 (don't forget that the values of image pixels are usually in the range [0,255], so dividing them by 255 makes them to fall in the range [0,1]):

```
train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255.0
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255.0
```